# TCL access array by reference/name

Tags: arrays, reference, tcl

Let's say I have a regular variable that contains the name of an existing array.

```
array set myarr {
    key_1 val_2
    key_2 val_2
}

set myvar myarr
```

I can found nowhere how I can iterate over myarr from myvar!

Comment: Just write `$myvar` where you would otherwise write `myarr`. Such as in `array names $myvar`.

Comment: Thanks Peter! The following seems to work: foreach {key value} [array get $myvar] {
    puts "$key => $value"
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `myvar` is a simple variable that is holding the ***name*** of another variable. You can use a read from it (with `$` or `set`) anywhere where you'd expect to use the name of the variable:

```
foreach {key value} [array get $myvar] {
    puts "$key => $value"
}
```

What you can't do directly is use the name to access the contents of the array. To do that, you'd usually use `upvar 0` to map the named thing to something that you can work with more easily:

```
upvar 0 $myvar v
foreach key [lsort [array names v]] {
    puts "$key => $v($key)"
}
```

(In this case, and provided you're using Tcl 8.6, you could use the `-stride` option to `lsort` to work with `array get` instead of `array names`, which would let you avoid making the alias. But that's a different way to achieve the same output really, and only applies if you're doing key-sorted array iteration…)